# Units in stoichiometry

Tags: stoichiometry

$$C_x H_y O_z$$

1.What are the units of x,y,z.I've read that they're termed as 'stoichiometric coefficients'.

2.What is the unit of mass proportion of carbon(c) in the fuel?

$$c=\frac{M_{carbon}}{M_{fuel}} .x$$

Answer (score 1):

The stoichiometric coefficients is something else than you suggest.

[stoichiometric coefficients](https://www.boundless.com/chemistry/definition/stoichiometric-coefficient/):

The number of molecules of a given component that participate in the reaction as written.

The indexes $x, y, z$ represent quantities of atoms in a compound. So they do not have any units.

@Q2 Do you know what are $c, M$ and $x$ in the equation? If you do, you can answer your question. If you do not, than you should find it out.

Comment: The book doesn't say what M stands for.But,I'm guessing its the molecular weight(g) or the molar mass(g/mol).Which one of these would be of apt use here?

Comment: If we assume that both $M_c$ and $M_f$ have the same units than what you got from the dimensional analysis?

Comment: I do not want to give you straight answer as the question seems to be part of a homework.